# deleting document from cosmos db using C# and cosmos client

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, delete-row, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am new to Cosmos DB and after reading through the microsoft docs am attempting to delete records from a cosmos db. I have tried to follow the example as closely as possible. The record is being found and read but I am running into a not found error when attempting to delete.

The collection is partitioned, and I have mentioned partition key as mentioned in the examples, but still results in an error.

```
    private async Task QueryItemsAsync()
    {
        var sqlQueryText = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.tenantId = '5c6cb2d77c1c2edc001b9007' and c.id = 'abae8abf-5836-464f-8129-1f0e83a1f639'";

        QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sqlQueryText);
        FeedIterator<Order> queryResultSetIterator = this.container.GetItemQueryIterator<Order>(queryDefinition);

        List<Order> orders = new List<Order>();

        while (queryResultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
        {
            FeedResponse<Order> currentResultSet = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
            foreach (Order o in currentResultSet)
            {
                orders.Add(o);
                Console.WriteLine("\tRead {0}\n", o);       
            }
        }
    }         
    private async Task DeleteFamilyItemAsync()
    {
        var partitionKeyValue = "tenantId";
        var orderId = "abae8abf-5836-464f-8129-1f0e83a1f639";

        // Delete an item. Note we must provide the partition key value and id of the item to delete
        ItemResponse<Order> orderResponse = await this.container.DeleteItemAsync<Order>(orderId, new PartitionKey(partitionKeyValue));
        Console.WriteLine("Deleted Family [{0},{1}]\n", partitionKeyValue, orderId);
    }
```

As seen below the record is being read so it is being found but when I attempt to delete it, it is not being deleted.
Read {"Id":null,"patientId":null,"orchestrationId":null,"preOrderId":"88557ec1-dccb-4397-9ce4-20b6aeb1d636","cartId":"adc463ef-7f38-4fa8-8f37-e505db3a5134","confirmationNum":"QDQ-9244014-14708","cartConfirmationNum":"IBM-8622967-14079","countryCode":null,"type":"order","cancelDate":null,"id":"abae8abf-5836-464f-8129-1f0e83a1f639"}

NotFound error occurred: CosmosRequestException;StatusCode=NotFound;SubStatusCode=0;ActivityId=6dd52d23-68c8-4e6d-b4ff-70cd2a6921cf;RequestCharge=1.24;Message=Response status code does not indicate success: 404 Substatus: 0 Reason: ().;
End of demo, press any key to exit.

Comment: I have tried to follow this example to a T. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-get-started

Comment: did you try executing the query on data explorer and you got results?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is with your `partitionKeyValue`. You are providing the partition key definition instead of the value. The value is the actual tenant id not the text `tenantId`.

Your delete code should then look like this:

```
private async Task DeleteFamilyItemAsync()
{
    var partitionKeyValue = "5c6cb2d77c1c2edc001b9007"; // <-- This is the change
    var orderId = "abae8abf-5836-464f-8129-1f0e83a1f639";

    // Delete an item. Note we must provide the partition key value and id of the item to delete
    ItemResponse<Order> orderResponse = await this.container.DeleteItemAsync<Order>(orderId, new PartitionKey(partitionKeyValue));
    Console.WriteLine("Deleted Family [{0},{1}]\n", partitionKeyValue, orderId);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nick, I was able to delete it.

Comment: Is there a way of doing it WITHOUT casting the item to a specific type (in this case: <Order>) ? It find it infuriating that I need to be so specific (correct id AND correct partition key AND correct type) to be able to simply delete something. If the deserialization of the object doesn't work (which is my current problem) then you simply can't delete an item!